# UITableView crashing after deleting an item from Parse Array

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery, viewdidappear

I have an iOS app that uses Parse for it's backend. I have a "User" class that has an array "myBooks" that contains pointers to objects from the class "Books".

I have two view controllers (vc1, vc2) that displays all of a user's books. Vc1 loads the books of every user in descending order according to createdAt. Vc2 is specific to PFUser.currentUser, thus it is a list of books for just each individual user that exists (I.e., vc1 has 30 total books, vc2 has 8 books from this current user that's logged in).

The issue at hand:
I have implemented a swipe-to-delete function for users to delete their books from the database and it is done successfully. The new array of books is updated and saved into the database for the current user with the removed book no longer present. When I go back to vc1 (I am using a tab bar controller), I have a viewDidAppear function trying to reload data from the database and reload the tableview. Unfortunately, when scrolling down the tableview the app always crashes with an out of bounds error. HOWEVER, I have a refresh button in vc1 that if I press 1-2 times after getting back to vc1, the crash is evaded.

How do I get the bookArray to actually load and update the tableview from the very initial return to vc1?

viewDidAppear function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil{

        self.loginVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LoginViewController
        self.presentViewController(self.loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    else{
        PFUser.currentUser()!.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                //do nothing
            }
            else{
                let errorCode = error!.code
                switch errorCode{
                case 209:
                    PFUser.logOut()
                    self.loginVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("login") as! LoginViewController
                    self.presentViewController(self.loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                default:
                    break
                }

            }
        })
    }
    self.loadData()

}
```

loadData function:

```
func loadData(){
        bookListing.removeAll()


        let checkForNewBookData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Book")
        checkForNewBookData.orderByDescending("createdAt")


        checkForNewBookData.findObjectsInBackground().continueWithSuccessBlock({ //sets up local data store correctly
            (task: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            return PFObject.unpinAllObjectsInBackgroundWithName("LocalBooks").continueWithSuccessBlock({
                (ignored: BFTask!) -> AnyObject! in

                // Cache new results
                let books = task.result as! [PFObject]
                self.bookListing.removeAll()
                self.bookListing = books
                let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                userDefaults.setObject("true", forKey: "localData")
                return PFObject.pinAllInBackground(books as [PFObject], withName: "LocalCabs")
            })
        })


        let getBookData = PFQuery(className: "Book")
        getBookData.orderByDescending("createdAt")
        getBookData.fromLocalDatastore()

        getBookData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects : [PFObject]?, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil{
                if let objects = objects{
                    for object in objects{
                        self.bookListing.append(object)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
            else{
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Something went wrong. Try again.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually run `self.tableView.reloadData()` **after** you receive data from the server?  At first glance, seems like reloadData() gets called first then your completion block updates your local data.

If that's the case, then your array is definitely out of sync with your table datasource.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reason you're getting strange results with the `reloadData` portion of this request is that you're calling `reloadData` on a background queue, which will make it happen at an unpredictable time.  To fix that you can put that portion of the call back on the main queue like this:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    ]
```

That should at least fix the issue you're having with the table reloading many seconds after you think it should.  I have to say, though, that I don't entirely understand why you force the user to log out and back in after that first function call.  I also think that you may have a potential problem with having two asynchronous calls happening that both modify the same property, `self.bookListing`.  You may want to consider putting the second query into a separate function and calling that from within the completion of the first function.  That way you're able to guarantee the first query finishes before the second one does.

Finally, similar to the `tableView.reloadData()` issue, you'll have the same problem presenting the `UIAlertController` from a background queue.

Comment: The log out in viewDidAppear is for something completely different; when user's change their passwords their session token is invalidated so I force a log out to get a new session token. I will implement your suggestions and hope they solve it, so thank you for the suggestions!